# ASan: How to use Sanitizer Special Case List with methods?

Tags: c++, llvm, clang++, address-sanitizer, thread-sanitizer

I want to disable ASan and TSan checks for one method in a project and the option llvm provides is a [Sanitizer special case list](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/SanitizerSpecialCaseList.html).

Here is a small example code which triggers an AddressSanitizer error.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <memory>

class BadASan
{
public:
  void get_memory()
  {
    int *a = reinterpret_cast<int *>(malloc(40));
    a[10] = 1;
  }
};

int main()
{
  auto bad_asan = std::make_unique<BasASan>();
  bad_asan->get_memory();
  return 0;
}
```

I have a file `ignorelist.txt` to tell ASan to ignore `BadASan::get_memory()`, but none of the pattern I tried so far are working. Every line starting with `fun:` I tried on its own or with combination of others

```ini
[address]
fun:BadASan::get_memory       # fully qualified name
fun:*get_memory               # pattern with only the method name
fun:__ZN3BadASan7get_memoryEv # mangled name
```

I compile the code with:

```shell
# clang++ -std=c++17 -fsanitze=address -fsanitize-ignorelist=ignorelist.txt bad_asan.cxx
```

but still the AddressSanitizer is showing the error.

How do I disable ASan for the method `BadASan::get_memory` with an ignorelist?

Answer (score 0):

Disabling LSan seems a little more complicated than just the ignorelist. The [clang documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html) redirects to [full documentation](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerLeakSanitizer#suppressions) which has the answer.

Have a file `suppr.txt` with the content

```
leak:get_memory
```

And another file `ignorelist.txt` with content

```
fun:*get_memory*
```

Compile with

```bash
clang++ -fsanitize=address -fsanitize-ignorelist=ignorelist.txt main.cpp
```

Then run with

```bash
ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=1 LSAN_OPTIONS=suppressions=suppr.txt ./a.out
```

Comment: Also of interest might be this issue: https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues/1628 which provides ways to supress leaksanitizers during compile time.